# How to determine if Server 2003 software is valid online?

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing

What is the best way to determine if the licensing for Server software purchased online is valid for our company?  For example, [this copy of Server 2003](http://www.trustprice.com/556813/microsoft-windows-server-2003-enterprise.html) seems entirely too cheap (we are planning to migrate to Server 2003 from Linux, can't use Server 2008 due to old Win98 machines), but if it's valid we'll certainly pick up a copy.  Any advice?

Comment: If a price seems to be too good to be true it probably is.

Comment: Damn! Those guys still sell Windows 95!

Comment: P.S. When you click the link for "Why is our price so low?" you get a 404... sounds a bit suss!

Comment: That's one of the places we still buy 95 and 98 licenses (we have some old software that uses hardware interrupts, only runs on 95/98).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't know of any way to verify that the products are genuine as it requires having access to the product key which, obviously, is not going to be handed out without a purchase agreement.

Windows 2003 licenses are coming down in price because of the release of Windows 2008.  Caveat emptor.  If you don't trust a vendor, don't buy from them.  If you do purchase and find a problem with the license then you can [**contact the Microsoft Anti-Piracy folks**](http://www.microsoft.com/piracy/reporting/default.aspx).  Microsoft takes piracy very seriously.  I personally have no experience in working with them, but I would imagine that they would help to address your issue in a fairly timely fashion.

Comment: I've worked with MS Piracy in the past. They are willing to look into a vendor and advise if the product is legitimate or not. You can ask them for clarification if you are hesitant. Also, they won't steer you away to another vendor that charges more (assuming this one is real), because they care how many SKUs are sold, not how much the vendors make.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the validity of a running copy of Windows by going to http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/default.aspx?displaylang=en and clicking on Validate Windows.  As far as pre-sales go, your best bet is to buy your licenses from reputable vendors that you trust.